# How to enable spelling correction in postman

Tags: tooltip, postman, autocorrect, spelling

While writing description in Postman tool, I need to correct spelling mistakes sometimes., is any option available to correct spelling mistakes in the postman app automatically.

Comment: Nope. You _could_ use a text editor to spell check the markdown and then paste that into your descriptions.

Comment: @DannyDainton yes I can do sometimes, most of the time it is complicated for huge services., Please indicate wrong words as red color, I will correct apparently., Danny can you implement this feature in next release of postman.

Comment: That's not really how software development works on a project like Postman...or any project in fact. You can raise a feature request on the Github repo stating all the information about the problem you want it to solve and it will get prioritised against all the other things that our users want to see.

Comment: @DannyDainton ok. I will request this feature. Thanks